Old British puppet series from the 1960s. Not Gerry Anderson
In the current British series Noel Fieldings Luxury Comedy, there is a character called Big Chief Woolabum Boomalackaway. I am sure I remember a character with that name who sang a song featuring the word Boomalackaway in a children's puppet series back in the late 1960s. I think it was set in the jungle, and Big Chief Woolabum was a grass-skirt-wearing native. Can anyone else remember this, or did I imagine it?

This is Sugarball the Little Jungle Boy, which aired in 1968.
The Character in question was called 'Big Chief Bilbo', but his song apparently held the lyrics:
"Big chief Bilbo 's getting very cross, bumalagwee"
"Don't you know that I'm the boss? bumalagwee"


I don't suppose anyone knows if any footage exists. I've looked on Youtube, but so far found nothing. Did this series suffer from the dreaded ITV wipe?

Doesn't seem to be John, unfortunately. Not many means of attaining archive footage either, regrettably.

Thanks Ghostdog and John Smith Optional. You have both been very helpfull.
